# Closures With Es5 and Es6

Tags: javascript, closures, arrow-functions

```
var add = function add(x, z) {
  if (z == undefined) {
    return function(y) {
      return x + y;
    }
  } else {
    return x + z
  }
}
```

The above code work well
when i write code with arrow function not work

```
var add = add(x, z) => {
  if (z == undefined) {
    return (y) => {
      return x + y;
    }
  } else {
    return x + z
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `add` in front of your parenthesis. `add(x, z)` -> `(x, z)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wrong syntax, as an arrow function should be declared like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)

Replace `add(x, z) =>` with `(x, z) =>`

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the add key word, try to use const and let declaratio because them are block scoping, with var you allocate innecesary memori with the hositing of varables in JS

```
const add = (x, z) => {
  if (z == undefined) {
    return (y) => {
      return x + y;
    }
  } else {
    return x + z
  }
}
```

Comment: nothing tells you that he doesn't need the `add` to be global scoped...

Comment: if he need to use it on another point, he can create in a block up in the function or class, remcoment this because it can cause a problem in teh future. @LiadYogev

Comment: and if he uses it in different scopes? the point is that it is defiantly okay to declare it as a var, if he needs it to be a var.

Comment: If he use in different scopes in the class he can declare outside the any function and all the functions can have acces to it, or if it need to use in anothe class export it simple, but the point is the hoisting that i was explained about the use of var in JS, that alocate memory at the begining of the execution and maybe he not use.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing but wrong syntax. Have fun.

```
var add = (x, z) => {
  if (z == undefined) {
    return (y) => {
      return x + y;
    }
  } else {
    return x + z;
  }
}
```